# Django: How Add Static Files

Tags: django, file, static

Readed all these topic https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=django.views.static.serve
And it not helped :(

OS: Windows XP
Python: 2.7
Django: 1.2.3

**Media in**
D:\bugtracker\static

**With files:**
 docicons-note.gif
 style.css

In **settings.py** i set:
MEDIA_ROOT = 'D:/bugtracker/static/'
MEDIA_URL = '/static/'

In **urls.py** i set:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    (r'^media/(?P.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve',{'document_root':'settings.MEDIA_ROOT'}),
)
```

**template:** (read it without space in < tag>)
`< !DOCTYPE html>
< html lang='ru'>

< head>

 < link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="media/style.css" />

< /head>

< body>

 < img src="{{MEDIA_URL}}/docicons-note.gif"/>

< /body>

< /html>`

Answer (score 5):

**urls.py:**

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    (r'^test_media/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve',   
        {'document_root':'settings.MEDIA_ROOT'}),
)
```

**settings.py**
    MEDIA_ROOT = 'path/to/media/folder/'

So if you have /test_media/photo.jpg will be used the value from MEDIA_ROOT: 
'path/to/media/folder/photo.jpg'

**template file:**

```
< !DOCTYPE html> < html lang='ru'>
< head>
< link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/test_media/style.css" />
< /head>
< body>
< img src="/test_media/docicons-note.gif"/>
< /body>
< /html>
```

This should be used only for development purposes. For production you should use a real web server.

Comment: make as u say, but server say: "/test_media/style.css HTTP 1.1" 404 1744.   Tryed: MEDIA_ROOT = 'D:/bugtracker/media_root/' and MEDIA_ROOT = 'D:\\bugtracker\\media_root\\'

Comment: Do you have the same 404 code for the photo(docicons-note.gif)? The css file is in the media_root folder or in media_root/css? You said the the media files are in D:\bugtracker\static. Then MEDIA_ROOT should be MEDIA_ROOT='D:/bugtracker/static'

Comment: That URLs method is not for production use as explained here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/static-files/#serving-static-files-during-development

Answer (score 2):

Your settings.py has:

```
MEDIA_URL = '/static/'
```

But in urls.py your static serve app is pointing to "media". Change your static serve entry in urls.py to match the MEDIA_URL setting:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    (r'^static/(?P.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve',{'document_root':'settings.MEDIA_ROOT'}),
)
```

Hopefully that works better for you.

Answer (score 0):

Static serving is only done via Django if the test server is running. If you're using a separate web server then you need to use that web server's facilities for serving static files, e.g. the `Alias` directive.